# PHP: Counting Extensions Occurence on a String

Tags: php, regex, file-extension

I have a webservice that return to me a string with a list of files uploaded, using `', '` as a separator.

**Example:** `01467_rbt.csv, 0152t.csv, 35302.png`

What I need to do is to counting how many times each extension appears on the string.

**Expected Result from Previous Example:** `.csv: 2 file(s); .png: 1 file(s)`

I'm using `preg_match_all` using **.\w\w\w** as regex, but I don't know the best way to do the following code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make something like that :

```
$string = '01467_rbt.csv, 0152t.csv, 35302.png';
$array = explode(", ", $string); // get an array with each filename

$result = array();

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $dexplode = explode(".", $value); // explode the filename on .
    $extension = end($dexplode); // get the last --> extension

    if(isset($result[$extension])) // if it's an existing extension
        $result[$extension]++; // add 1
    else // if not existing
        $result[$extension]=1; // init to 1
}

var_dump($result);
```

And, for example, to have the number of csv file :

```
$result["csv"];
```

This is the result of the var_dump() :

```
array (size=2)
  'csv' => int 2
  'png' => int 1
```

**Edit:**

You have many possibilities to find the file extension :

```
$filename = 'mypic.gif';

// 1. The "explode/end" approach
$ext = end(explode('.', $filename));

// 2. The "strrchr" approach
$ext = substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1);

// 3. The "strrpos" approach
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

// 4. The "preg_replace" approach
$ext = preg_replace('/^.*\.([^.]+)$/D', '$1', $filename);

// 5. The "never use this" approach
//   From: http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/qt/file_ext_PHP.htm
$exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename);
$n = count($exts)-1;
$ext = $exts[$n];
```

More detail [here](http://www.cowburn.info/2008/01/13/get-file-extension-comparison/)